# Generic Sorted List of Nodes Head Traversal Optimization Adding Elements from Two Lists

Tags: java, sorting, generics, optimization

I am working on a homework assignment meant to help me understand generic programming. This class, an ordered list class, uses a sequence of generic nodes to have a list in ascending order. My issue is I want to implement a method that functions like the addFrom method, but makes it more efficient. This method takes another ordered list object as a parameter and uses this ordered list in the method too. The addFrom method will identify the correct position and place the node in the correct position. However, I want to have the method traverse through the nodes of both lists exactly once. (As a tangent, I want to say this uses a both while loop and compareTo but not sure how to implement it.)

Before I posted this, I went to my professor's office hours and understood the theory of how you are supposed to iterate through the two lists, where you use the node we'll call the "head". The head goes through the elements of the two lists and compares the elements. If the one element is smaller, you add one to the counter associated with that list. This is how you are supposed to maintain order. But I cannot get the head to adapt to this adaptation.

I have a "working" version of this method that casts an object from the other list that always has the head start at the beginning of the list. This has the head start at the beginning of the list. But this always happens, and I don't want to do this.

I considered two approaches to this efficiency, one using a while loop to count how many elements are inserted; this goes on until we are hitting our size using two counters. I quickly threw this out because of because of an exception being thrown with the get method. (I hated doing things this way, but this felt like it made the most sense.) The other approach is just using two for loops (essentially disregarding the size issue) and then doing the comparisons, but both feel totally off the mark of actually making the method efficient. It almost looks like the "working" version. Both versions gave me a custom exception from another class. (Note, I am also considering making a size method that returns the attribute altogether.)

```
/**
 * Sorts a list of nodes with generic type.
 * @author John Doe
 * @param <T> user defined type
 */

public class OrderedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private Node<T> head;
  private int size;

  /**
   * Initializes a new ordered list object.
   */
  public OrderedList() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
  }
  
  /**
   * Creates a new node with a given item and inserts it into its correct
   * position in the list so that the list is in ascending order.
   * @param element newly inserted element
   */
  public void insert(T element) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(element, null);
    if (head == null) {
      head = newNode;
    } else {
      Node<T> current = head;
      Node<T> previous = null;
      while (current != null && current.data.compareTo(element) < 0) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
      }
      newNode.next = current;
      if (previous == null) {
        head = newNode;
      } else {
        previous.next = newNode;
      }
    }
    size++;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a copy of the k-th item in the list for a given integer k.
   * @param index the position the user specifies
   * @return The element the user wants to get
   * @throws OutOfBoundException if the index is out of bounds
   */
  public T get(int index) throws OutOfBoundException 
  {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) 
    {
      throw new OutOfBoundException("Index: " + index + " size: " + size);
    }
    Node<T> current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      current = current.next;
    }
    return current.data;
  }

  /**
   * Removes the first instance of a user-specified item.
   * @param item user specified item
   */
  public void remove(T item) 
  {
    Node<T> current = head;
    Node<T> previous = null;
    while (current != null) {
      if (item.equals(current.data)) {
        if (previous == null) {
          head = current.next;
        } else {
          previous.next = current.next;
        }
        size--;
      } else {
        previous = current;
      }
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
  
  /**
   * Returns the last k elements in this ordered list.
   * @param k number of elements to return
   * @return List of the k largest elements
   * @throws OutOfBoundException if the index is out of bounds
   */
  public OrderedList kLargest(int k) throws OutOfBoundException
  {
      if (k >= size || k < 0)
          k = Math.abs(size);
      OrderedList ol = new OrderedList();
      for (int i = size - k; i < size; i++)
      {
          ol.insert(get(i));
      }
      return ol;
  }
  
  /**
   * Temporary, crappy method doing what add(OrderedList list2) should do;
   * it should traverse through the nodes of this list and the other nodes
   * exactly one without having to repeatedly search the location where the
   * items should be added to on the new list.
   * @param list2 another ordered list
   * @return Elements from both ordered list
   * @throws OutOfBoundException if the index is out of bounds
   */
  public OrderedList addFrom(OrderedList list2) throws OutOfBoundException
  {
      OrderedList list3 = new OrderedList();
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
          list3.insert(get(i));
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < list2.size; j++)
      {
          T element = (T) list2.get(j);
          list3.insert(element);
      }
      return list3;
  }
  
  /**
   * Method of implementing proper version of "addFrom" should do with proper
   * efficiency.
   * @param list2 another ordered list
   * @return Elements from both ordered list
   * @throws OutOfBoundException if the index is out of bounds
   */
  public OrderedList add(OrderedList list2) throws OutOfBoundException
  {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    OrderedList list3 = new OrderedList();
    int k = i + j;
    while (k < this.size + list2.size)
    {
        if(list2.get(i).compareTo(this.get(j)) < 0)
        {
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
            list3.insert(list2.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(this.get(j));
            list3.insert(this.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }
      return list3;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a neatly formatted list with every node.
   * @return A representation of the nodes in the list 
   */
  @Override
  public String toString() 
  {
    String st = "[";
    for (Node<T> n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
        st += n.data + ((n.next == null ? "]" : ", "));
    return st;
  }
}

/**
 * Establishes that a node object has data and a next node object.
 * @author John Doe
 * @param <T> user defined type
 */
class Node<T> {
  T data;       
  Node<T> next;

  /**
   * Initializes a new node object.
   * @param data specified user input
   * @param next what is the node next to
   */
  public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).